# Drupal migrate hierarchical taxonomy from XML source using entity_lookup

Tags: xml, drupal, migration

I'm migrating into a node on an existing Drupal 9 site from an XML file. One of the fields is an existing taxonomy with a two-level hierarchy. A sample of the XML for that part of the import looks like this:

```
<nrts>
  <nrt>
    <levelone>Fire</levelone>
    <leveltwo>Prescribed fire</leveltwo>
  </nrt>
  <nrt>
    <levelone>Natural Resource Management &amp; Use</levelone>
    <leveltwo></leveltwo>
  </nrt>
  <nrt>
    <levelone>Natural Resource Management &amp; Use</levelone>
    <leveltwo>Economics</leveltwo>
  </nrt>
</nrts>
```

The relevant part of my migration configuration looks like this (I'm using the [Migrate Process Vardump](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_process_vardump) plugin to give me debugging output):

```
field_nrt_1:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      source: nrt
      method: process
    -
      plugin: vardump
      header: 'Before processing'
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      process:
        target_id:
          plugin: entity_lookup
          entity_type: taxonomy_term
          bundle_key: vid
          bundle: national_research_taxonomy
          value_key: name
          ignore_case: true
```

The migration proceeds with no errors and there's nothing listed when I run drush migrate-messages. Here's the end of the output, with the taxonomy array provided by the vardump plugin:

```
Before processing: array(2) {
  ["levelone"]=>
  string(21) "Forest & Plant Health"
  ["leveltwo"]=>
  string(16) "Invasive species"
}
Before processing: array(2) {
  ["levelone"]=>
  string(33) "Inventory, Monitoring, & Analysis"
  ["leveltwo"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
 [notice] Processed 169 items (169 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'ximport054'
```

When I check my newly created nodes, everything else is there but field_nrt_1 remains empty. I have other single-level taxonomies coming over in the migration, so I know entity_lookup is working. I've tried the xml and simple_xml parsers and had the same results. Obviously I'm missing some little piece, but I'm at a loss for what it is.

I'd greatly appreciate any help to guide me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem. For the benefit of anyone else who might be struggling with this, I used the following config with the [Migrate Hierarchical Taxonomy](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_hierarchical_taxonomy) plugin and the following configuration:

```
  field_nrt_1:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      source: nrt
      method: process
    -
      plugin: vardump
      header: 'Before processing'
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      process:
        target_id:
          plugin: hierarchical_taxonomy
          entity_type: taxonomy_term
          bundle_key: vid
          bundle: national_research_taxonomy
          value_key: name
          ignore_case: true
          source:
            - levelone
            - leveltwo
```